# openconnect client hello dropped by DPI

Tags: authentication, openconnect

I've installed openconnect server (ocserv) and works perfectly when I tunnel (SSH) to the server through another server that is inside country. But when I try to connect directly, the "client hello" message doesn't deliver to the server and retransmit it. I think the government detects "client hello" and drops it. I had a little success when I used a proxy and initial connection occurred and I entered username and password but eventually didn't connect.
Is there any way such as encrypting "client hello" message or something like that?

Comment: your question is not clear, since you are talking about the censorship mechanism used in your country, thus this question is understandable only for the users living in the same country your living.

Comment: I just want handshake and authentication between anyconnect (or openconnect) and ocserv to be encrypted.